# Node module folder not in correct folder

Tags: node.js, npm-install, node-modules

So I have downloaded node from the node.org website v4.4.4 and I have a folder on my desktop called project I have cd into project and done a npm install socket.io

it install okay but i have noticed that I dont get a node_modul in my projects folder. But in Users/Rob/node_module and socket.io is there

Have I missed something out, or done something wrong?

Whenever I run a npm install say gulp I get

```
    Robs-MBP:chat Rob$ npm install gulp
npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "gulp"
npm ERR! node v4.4.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! path /Users/Rob/node_modules/.bin/gulp
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall unlink

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/Users/Rob/node_modules/.bin/gulp'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/Users/Rob/node_modules/.bin/gulp']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/Rob/node_modules/.bin/gulp' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/Users/Rob/node_modules/.bin/gulp'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/Users/Rob/node_modules/.bin/gulp']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/Users/Rob/node_modules/.bin/gulp' }

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Rob/Desktop/chat/npm-debug.log
Robs-MBP:chat Rob$ cd
Robs-MBP:~ Rob$ cd Desktop/web
Robs-MBP:web Rob$ npm install gulp
npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "gulp"
npm ERR! node v4.4.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! path /Users/Rob/node_modules/.bin/gulp
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall unlink

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/Users/Rob/node_modules/.bin/gulp'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/Users/Rob/node_modules/.bin/gulp']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/Rob/node_modules/.bin/gulp' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/Users/Rob/node_modules/.bin/gulp'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/Users/Rob/node_modules/.bin/gulp']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/Users/Rob/node_modules/.bin/gulp' }

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Rob/Desktop/web/npm-debug.log
Robs-MBP:web Rob$ sudo npm install gulp
Password:
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
gulp@3.9.1 ../../node_modules/gulp
├── interpret@1.0.1
├── pretty-hrtime@1.0.2
├── deprecated@0.0.1
├── archy@1.0.0
├── tildify@1.2.0 (os-homedir@1.0.1)
├── minimist@1.2.0
├── v8flags@2.0.11 (user-home@1.1.1)
├── semver@4.3.6
├── chalk@1.1.3 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.5, supports-color@2.0.0, ansi-styles@2.2.1, has-ansi@2.0.0, strip-ansi@3.0.1)
├── orchestrator@0.3.7 (stream-consume@0.1.0, sequencify@0.0.7, end-of-stream@0.1.5)
├── liftoff@2.2.1 (extend@2.0.1, rechoir@0.6.2, flagged-respawn@0.3.2, findup-sync@0.3.0, resolve@1.1.7)
├── vinyl-fs@0.3.14 (graceful-fs@3.0.8, strip-bom@1.0.0, defaults@1.0.3, vinyl@0.4.6, through2@0.6.5, mkdirp@0.5.1, glob-stream@3.1.18, glob-watcher@0.0.6)
└── gulp-util@3.0.7 (array-differ@1.0.0, array-uniq@1.0.2, lodash._reinterpolate@3.0.0, lodash._reevaluate@3.0.0, beeper@1.1.0, lodash._reescape@3.0.0, object-assign@3.0.0, replace-ext@0.0.1, has-gulplog@0.1.0, fancy-log@1.2.0, vinyl@0.5.3, gulplog@1.0.0, lodash.template@3.6.2, through2@2.0.1, multipipe@0.1.2, dateformat@1.0.12)
```

Then Ive even tried sudo npm install and it still wont put a node_module folder in that folder i am in. Instead it installs it in the node_module folder in my Users/Rob/node_module i cant understand why

Any help with solving this would be great.

Comment: I suppose you did global install with  `npm install socket.io -g`.

Comment: no just cd into the folder and done a normal install

Comment: I never encountered such behavior (on *nixes and Windows) but documentation https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders   tells that it's possible.
Search for: `Starting at the $PWD, npm will walk up the folder tree checking for a folder that contains either a package.json file, or a node_modules folder.`  Try  `npm init . ` in your folder. I suppose it could be solution for your problem.

Comment: So if I navigate to Desktop/web and then do a npm init then do a npm install gulp for example and it should fix it. Ive never seen it before and I've only just got my Mac

Comment: Also Installed v4 through the download on the node site, its just came up with this: Make sure that /usr/local/bin is in your $PATH. how would I do that? Just incase that's it? I've typed nose and I was able to do a console log and it worked.

Comment: Rob, I'm curious: did `npm init` resolved your problem?  Or even `mkdir node_modules`?

Comment: I will try them and let you know.

Comment: npm init worked :)

Comment: Turns out I had to do an npm init and now it all works. So can I delete that node module in my users file? Or is that where it globally installs all my node modules?

Comment: You can delete node_modules any time you want. Don't forget about --save, --save-dep. Cheers!

Comment: What are they? I've never come across them